# What was the 'Elephant movie'?

Tags: laurel-and-hardy, stan-and-ollie

In the *Stan & Ollie* biographical movie, there is a temporary separation in their partnership during which Oliver Hardy appears in a movie with a different partner. This movie, which is only referred to as 'The Elephant Movie' is a major bone of contention between Stan and Ollie.

What was 'The Elephant Movie' and how successful was it? Answers will need to reference the real-world history of the duo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"The Elephant Movie" was [*Zenobia* (1939)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0032158/) (titled "Elephants Never Forget" in the UK), and was the result of a contract dispute between Stan Laurel and producer Hal Roach, who had separate contracts for both Laurel and Hardy.  Roach did this to ensure they couldn't team up against him and it made it easier for him to control what they did.  Roach tried to pair Oliver Hardy with Harry Langdon to create a new comedic pairing, but that only lasted for a movie (Zenobia) before Roach and Laurel reached a new agreement.  Langdon had previously done some comedic writing for Laurel and Hardy, which was why Roach thought they'd make a good pair.

By all accounts, the film was a box office failure.  It cost $637,000 to make and grossed only $351,000 worldwide, according to the Langdon biography "Little Elf. "